# How to make protected route in next js 14?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, next.js13

Suppose I have an API that set accessToken in cookie when login. By using this cookie i can send a request to get the profile of user. user have different role. Such that "admin", "seller", "buyer". By using this how can i protect the different route in nextjs 14. If the cookie is not set I can not get the profile information.

**Question 1:** So how to do that in Server Side rendering or client Side Rendering or using middleware in nextjs.

**Question 2:** I have accessToken and also refresh token then how to do the same work?. The refresh token will expire in 3 minutes. So For this i have to make another request to validate the refresh token.

Note: I am not making the API in the next js. I am using express js to build the API and make this Login and registration and refresh token API manually.

Please give me your suggestions.  If possible to give me some code example to solve this problem or give me some reference.

My api end point is
**login** `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/login`

response

```
{
    email:"example@gmail.com",
    role:"admin"
}
```

**refresh token:** `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/refresh-token`

For the refresh token case how I call this API after certain time or on every request?

Comment: What about using `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: Try using middleware here is a great video that might help you understand it https://youtu.be/NUHAc1wjL3A?si=sl-Fb87l1KU_VxB_